# ? How can I get dart 2.13 compile statement: typedef IntList = List<int>;

Tags: syntax

This statement appears in several examples on the web; but when I try it, I get a compile error for the statement   typedef IntList = List;

Answer (score 0):

Your Dart SDK constraint must be set to support 2.13 features to use non-function `typedef`s. Simply updating your local Dart tool (or Flutter for that matter) will not work. You can set your constraint in a few ways:

1. in your `pubspec.yaml`, there is an `environment` parameter that you can use:

```
// pubspec.yaml

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.13.0 <3.0.0"  // sets the minimum Dart version to 2.13 for this package
```

2. In the first line of a tile, you can set a specific language version with a comment:

```
// @dart=2.13
import 'package:foo/foo.dart';

typedef Foo = String;
```

3. You can use method 2) in the entrypoint (i.e. the `main()` method) and it will apply it to that execution

Answer (score 0):

This problem goes deeper.

Less than a month ago (26 Oct) I used "flutter create --template=skeleton myproject" to start a new Flutter project based on the "skeleton" template, which is described as "a List View / Detail View Flutter application that follows community best practices". I had previously transcribed a Model class from C++ into Dart and tested it successfully. When I went to incorporate that class into my skeleton-based Flutter app, it failed to compile the line "typedef BoardContents = List;", which had always compiled before in a pure-Dart environment. I checked versions and found I have flutter 2.5.3 and dart 2.14.4. The problem turned out to be in the pubspec.yaml file supplied by "flutter create" of "skeleton".

ianw:~/0_flutterdev>cat skeleton/pubspec.yaml
name: skeleton
description: A new Flutter project.

## Prevent accidental publishing to pub.dev.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

Flutter is setting an out-of-date Dart version in a template that is described as following "community best practices".

Comment: Apologies, my post got garbled a little, but the sense is OK. The "typedef BoardContents" referred to should be a List of type int.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).